# Visual Studio doesn't recognize functions in my class

Tags: c#, class

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to write C# code. I've added a reference to a class to my Window application solution named BotSuit.

In my code I added:

```
using BotSuite;
```

When I want to use the functions in my class, BotSuite, I need to type this for it to work.

```
ListGold = BotSuite.ImageLibrary.Template.AllImages(source, refpic, 24);
```

Why can't I just type this?

```
ListGold = AllImages(source, refpic, 24);
```

Comment: because of namespaces. add `using BotSuite.ImageLibrary` to the top of your file, then you can say `Template.AllImages()`

Comment: The `using` keyword gives you easy access to the given namespace, but it does not automatically give you access to namespaces within the given namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a using statement to the top of your file:

```
using BotSuite.ImageLibrary.Template;
```

or

```
using BotSuite.ImageLibrary;
```

...

```
Template.AllImages(source, refpic, 24);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but why doesn't it recognize everything under ´using BotSuite;´ That would be much more simple?

Comment: Because that would potentially pull in too much, even introducing conflicting names.  `using System;` would pull in most of the .NET framework, and there are some conflicting class names in there.

Comment: Some languages have the equivalent of "using BotSuite.*" or similar, but not in C#.  In C# you need to be more explicit for reasons stated by Eric J.

Answer (score 0):

In C# your classes exists in namespaces. You can think of it as of a directory in which compiler can locate your code. If you want to use a class from one namespace in a class from another namespace you have to let the compiler know where to look for it. To do that use the using` keyword. It tells the compiler to include code from different namespaces.